Git missing from win10 debian wsl, libc6 version prevents install with apt-get
Git is not seen by WSL after installing for windows.
Using apt-get install git gives the following error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.31-13+deb11u9 is to be installed
       Recommends: ssh-client
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

when I attempt apt-get install libc6=2.38 I get
Version '2.38' for 'libc6' was not found
this is after
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install

This is with a fresh install of WSL using Debian on Windows 10.
The only solutions I've found online are for Ubuntu linux boxes and are about upgrading libc6 or similar, not relevant to installing git and the unmet dependency issue.

You likely have mixed distributions in your APT sources list(s).

No. You check your APT sources to make sure they all points at the same version of Debian. (Also note that “deb” at the beginning of a line doesn’t refer to a distribution or version.)

SOLVED
I was able to find a solution via this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/334075
I installed aptitude, and then used it to install git.
Aptitude does more work to find solutions to unmet dependencies and the second solution it came up with was just to install an older version of git that didn't depend on the higher version of libc6.
